# Google Drive API - update file metadata only

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-apis-explorer

I am trying to rename google drive file resource. I guess that I just am missing something since all other actions like getting list of files, inserting files, moving files between directories are working.

Precondition: trying to rename file resource using this doc https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/update with java (with only JDK stuff). Also, I do not use gdrive java sdk, apache http client or other libraries... Just clean JDK tools.

So what I do:

1. [Here](https://gist.github.com/romanshvets/0e55ff083a3467e0a09cbe78f77884fa) is the file metadata I am trying to send.
2. Modify `title` property in this metadata
3. Here is the code:

   ```
   URLConnection urlConnection = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/" + fileId).openConnection();

   if (urlConnection instanceof HttpURLConnection) {
       HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) urlConnection;
       httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
       httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
       httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);

       DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());
       outputStream.writeBytes(FILE_RESOURCE_METADATA_WITH_CHANGED_TITLE_IN_JSON);
       outputStream.flush();
       outputStream.close();
   }
   ```

After making an actual call to API I receive 200 status code and File resource in response body (as expected) but title remains the same. So I got no error no changed title.

Moreover, the google drive api ignores any change in the file resource. It just returns same file resource without any changes applied (tried with title, description, originalFileName, parents properties).

What I tried also so far:

1. Sending only the properties that should be changed, like

   ```
   {"title":"some_new_name"}
   ```

Result is same.

2. Changing `PUT` to `PATCH`. Unfortunately, `PATCH` is not supported by HttpURLConnection but workarounds gave same results. Changes are ignored.
3. Used google api exlorer (which can be found on the right side of API reference page) - and... it works. Filled only fileId and title property in request body and it worked. File is renamed.

What I am missing ?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution...

Adding this request property fixed the problem.

```
httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the sample java code given in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/update).

Since the code deals to update existing file's metadata and content.

From the code, you will find `file.setTitle(newTitle)` which I think the one what you want to implement.

```
import com.google.api.client.http.FileContent;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.File;

import java.io.IOException;
// ...

public class MyClass {

  // ...

  /**
   * Update an existing file's metadata and content.
   *
   * @param service Drive API service instance.
   * @param fileId ID of the file to update.
   * @param newTitle New title for the file.
   * @param newDescription New description for the file.
   * @param newMimeType New MIME type for the file.
   * @param newFilename Filename of the new content to upload.
   * @param newRevision Whether or not to create a new revision for this
   *        file.
   * @return Updated file metadata if successful, {@code null} otherwise.
   */
  private static File updateFile(Drive service, String fileId, String newTitle,
      String newDescription, String newMimeType, String newFilename, boolean newRevision) {
    try {
      // First retrieve the file from the API.
      File file = service.files().get(fileId).execute();

      // File's new metadata.
      file.setTitle(newTitle);
      file.setDescription(newDescription);
      file.setMimeType(newMimeType);

      // File's new content.
      java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File(newFilename);
      FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent(newMimeType, fileContent);

      // Send the request to the API.
      File updatedFile = service.files().update(fileId, file, mediaContent).execute();

      return updatedFile;
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
      return null;
    }
  }

  // ...
}
```

Hope this give you some points.